# Getting Terms of that satisfy two taxonomies in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get only those terms that satisfy two custom post type taxonomies i.e I want to only show those colours which are in tilesize 25x33 where colour and tilesize are my custom post type taxonomies.

I have tried using the code below, but this still shows all colours rather than in tilezise 25x33.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'tilesizes'=>'25x33');
$colour = get_terms("colour" $args);
if ( !empty( $colour ) && !is_wp_error( $colour ) ){
$colourtag = '';
foreach ( $colour as $colour ) {
$colourtag .=  '<label><input type="checkbox" rel="' . $colour->name .'"/> '.$colour-  >name.' </label>';

}}

echo '<div class="refinetags">'.$colourtag.'</div>';
```

Please help in how i can achieve this

Comment: where you have used `$args` ?

Comment: @TechnoKnol thanks, i've updated my question where I use $args but still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

you haven't passed `$args` in `get_terms()`

### [Refer this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

You are passing only first argument which is `taxonomy` ('colour' in your case. )

Here first argument can be array or string.

***[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57444/get-terms-by-custom-post-type)*** may help you.

Comment: `$colour = get_terms("colour" $args);` tried using but still no luck

Comment: you forgot colon (`,`) between two arguments, have you read DOC i have linked in my answer .